# SQL server error The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided

Tags: sql-server-2008

SQL server error The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. 
    I am trying to restore a 200 MB database into SQL 2008 and I am getting this error

> "The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided

[image]

Comment: The backup spans 2 files, you need both to restore

Answer (score 23):

You are getting this error because your database backup was striped and the backup stream was split into two destination files. You are trying to restore from a single backup file. You need both files to restore your database.

For more information on the error, refer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/abf50e00-c9b0-4809-9e61-43ed8a53e968/the-media-set-has-2-media-families-but-only-1-are-provided?forum=sqltools)

Comment: I used the SSMS GUI to make a backup. There was a device already set up, so I added a second one.Then, when making a backup, I specifically selected my new file thinking the backup would go to that one file. I already was kinda amazed that the file was about half as big as I expected, but thought that the server might have a weird default for compression... Turns out it didn't use my selected file, but both files present to stripe half of the backup to each file...

Answer (score 12):

its kinda late but here's how I managed to fix this issue.

It seems that you have left another location while doing the back-up. Delete the other location and keep your specified one.

[image]

Putting two locations would stripe the file into two parts, meaning you need two files to complete the restoration.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

you have set two backup locations !
You can change it to one location when you want to backup .
sorry for my english .

Comment: THIS was my problem. The "Back Up Database" window had pre-populated the "Destination" list with a destination in "Program Files/SQL Server" folder. I mistakenly left that entry and "Add"ed the file I intended it to go to. Delete any pre-populated destination(s) first!

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but in case someone comes around here again later (like me), this can maybe help:

If you don't have the possibility to recreate the backup, and you have both files, you can restore the database by going to `Tasks > Restore > Database` and click on `From Device`.

The choice of `Database` in the menu is the important point. It doesn't seem possible to me to restore a database divided into several files using `Files and Filegroups` menu.

Thanks to Hamid Sirat's answer, in the link posted previously by ughai ([here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/abf50e00-c9b0-4809-9e61-43ed8a53e968/the-media-set-has-2-media-families-but-only-1-are-provided?forum=sqltools)) for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the .bak file backup of your database using MS SQL server managment studio, Task->Backup..., on destination section you probably have 2 folders included in the list. Remove one and all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but I encountered this recently and all of the existing answers talk about how *not to* backup to multiple families - which is absolutely reasonable in a preventative sense.

However, if you're like me and have inherited backups that are already split and need something useful from them, note:

```
[ FROM <backup_device> [ ,...n ] ]
```

The From clause in a backup restore statement allows you to specify multiple devices/families. If you're restoring from flat files, it would look something like:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDatabase] FROM DISK = N'\\path\to\file1.bak', DISK = N'\\path\to\file2.bak'
```

Answer (score -2):

If your problem persists with the above, I should suggest you reinstall or install a new version of SQL.
Because it is likely that your software has a problem or your software version is older than the software version of the backup manufacturer.
However, you must install SQL again.